# How to prepend data to the binary file?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I have a big binary file. How I can write (prepend) to the begin of the file?

Ex:

```
file = 'binary_file'
string = 'bytes_string'
```

I expected get new file with content: `bytes_string_binary_file`.

Construction `open("filename", ab)` appends only.

I'm using Python 3.3.1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to prepend to a file. You **must** rewrite the file completely:

```
with open("oldfile", "rb") as old, open("newfile", "wb") as new:
    new.write(string)
    new.write(old.read())
```

If you want to avoid reading the whole file into memory, simply read it by chunks:

```
with open("oldfile", "rb") as old, open("newfile", "wb") as new:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: old.read(1024), b""):
        new.write(chunk)
```

Replace `1024` with a value that works best with your system. (it is the number of bytes read each time).

Comment: Thank you very much for solution, but my operating memory is limited.. Is maybe another solution? Or isn't possible?

Comment: @wikicms Added a solution that only uses limited memory, using the [`iter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) function.

Comment: OMG, You master in python! Thanks!